# NSOutlineView method shouldSelectItem return null object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am using NSOutlineView in my Cocoa app. It is working fine but some time this method

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldSelectItem:(id)item
```

and some other NSOutlineView default methods return me object item like:

```
(id) item = 0x00000001005a71f0
```

Printing description of [0]:

```
(<invalid>) [0] = <error: function 'null' with unknown type must be given a function type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
>
```

While It should be always `NSTreeNode` type. If i check as

```
if(item)
   NSLog(@"%@",[item description]);
```

My app is crashing on `NSLog` line.

I had already spent my half day to find out reason and try to resolve it. But still not succeeded.
Can any one help me, why it is happening with default methods of `NSOutlineView`.

Thanks

Comment: 1. What does the debugger say item is?  2. While I also more or less assume a type of NSTreeNode, my functions are always checking isKindOfClass.  3. [Item description] can be replaced with simply item in the NSLog. (You don't have to invoke the description method in a %@ context)

Comment: 1). Debugger says item is? - It is (id) item = 0x00000001005a71f0(<invalid>) [0] = <error: function 'null' with unknown type must be given a function type
error: 1 errors parsing expression               2).  I tried to check for isKindOfClass too, if i do this very first, then it crash on this line.       3).  [item description] or item on both case, it is also crashing.

Comment: Huh.  Maybe item is a pointer to garbage, which is unusual with Objective-C w/ ARC.  [This article is perhaps over the top](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/testing-if-arbitrary-pointer-is-valid.html) but it does say, "The object associated with the notification is passed as a void *. Most of the time, the value in object will be an Objective-C object but for the few times when it isn't, simply passing the result into NSLog can cause your program to crash." ... `id` should be type-checked, though.  +1 vote just because I'm baffled.

Comment: Err, wait.  What suggested `[0]`? ... and try `po item` in the console when breaking on the NSLog line.

Comment: Using `po item`  it return `[no Objective-C description available]`